# Django search in Postgresql db_collation field

Tags: django, postgresql, collation

I'm using Django and DRF searchFilter, which allows me to add fields to the view's 'search_fields' to allow searching in them.
Django version is 3.2 (will probably upgrade to 4.2) and DRF version 3.12.2.
Lately I've added a new field of type `CharField` with a db_collation of `case_insensitive`. I need that field to be case-insensitive and I understood that Postgres will stop supporting `CI` field and the recommendation is using db_collation. It did work until I wanted to support searching in that field. After adding that new field to the 'search_fields' of the view and trying searching, I got this error message -

```
 File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) 
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: nondeterministic collations are not supported for LIKE
```

Is there a pre-prepared solution for that?
I couldn't find any and I find it weird that Postgres enforce using db_collation but doesn't support LIKE in it.

This is the field definition in the model -

```
custom_field = models.CharField(db_collation="case_insensitive", db_index=True, max_length=100, null=True)
```

This is the collation definition -

```
[
    CreateCollation(
        "case_insensitive",
        provider="icu",
        locale="und-u-ks-level2-kn-true",
        deterministic=False,
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33901), This has been fixed in Django 4.2. A workaround for Django 3 (3.2.x, to be exact) is to subclass the Postgres SchemaEditor to override its `_create_like_index_sql` method and use the adjusted backend in the DATABASES entries.

If a `varchar_pattern_ops` index exists on the Postgres DB, altering the field may not be sufficent and it may need to be recreated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @PGzlan. Actually, it's not the same issue. I've already faced that issue and had to fix it in order to get to the current one

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the issue is with queries containing `LIKE`. If so, that [may not be supported by PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html):

> Also, certain operations are not possible with nondeterministic collations, such as pattern matching operations. Therefore, they should be used only in cases where they are specifically wanted.